# Mapping built-in UserProfile to UserProfileId column in table

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a table Tale with definition

```
public class Tale
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public int enum_TaleAuthorTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual enum_TaleAuthorType enum_TaleAuthorType { get; set; }

    public int CommentableId { get; set; }
    public virtual Commentable Commentable { get; set; }
}
```

and when i type 'update-database' in console, i have nice relationships with one column for CommentableId and one for enum_TaleAuthorTypeId.

Now, i'd like to add UserProfile and try to type something like:

```
public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
```

but after add-migration, i have this:

```
AddColumn("dbo.Tales", "UserProfileId", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
AddColumn("dbo.Tales", "UserProfile_UserId", c => c.Int());
```

How should i get just one column for value? Why it's create two columns?

Comment: One more time without answer...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that, by convention, EF expects the primary key of `UserProfile` to be `Id`, but you have it as `UserId`.

You can either change the property name of `UserId` in `UserProfile` to `Id` so that EF infers the key by convention, or override the convention and keep `UserId` as the primary key.

You can override the convention using attributes e.g.

```
[ForeignKey("UserProfileId")]
public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
```

or using the Fluent API e.g.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Tale>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.UserProfile)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(u => u.UserProfileId);

}
```